# How do I make menu background even with the header in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

Problem: Can't make menu background even with header. (you will see it in picture)

[PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zIXA.jpg)

How to cut them off?

CSS CODE :

```
.header {
    margin:0px auto;
    max-width: 960px;
}

#header {
    height:300px;
    width:960px;
    background-image:url("img/top.png")
}
#menu ul {
    margin:0px auto;
    margin-left:-59px;
    list-style: none;
    background:#3d3d5c;
}

#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#menu li a  {
    color:#fff; 
    text-decoration:none; 
    display:block; 
    background:url(img/manu.png); 
    padding:0 10px 0 10px;  
    height:54px; 
    width:130px;
    line-height:54px;
}

#menu li a:hover {
    color:#fff; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    background:url(img/manu1.png);  
    height:54px; 
    width:130px;
    line-height:54px;
}
```

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cvk5a3nn/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below updated will should solve your problem:

```
#menu ul {
    margin:0px auto;
    margin-left:-20px; /*pull towards left*/
    margin-right:20px; /*push towards right*/
    list-style: none;
    background:#3d3d5c;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These modifications should solve it

```
.header {
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 960px;
}
```

And remove the margin from the `ul`

```
#menu ul {
    margin: 0px auto;
    list-style: none;
    background: #3d3d5c;
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/cvk5a3nn/8/)